Java free(): double free detected in tcache2 when using BufferedImage
got an interesting issue I am trying to figure out.
No other logs are provided in this crash.
It also gets double free or corruption (fasttop) on an occasion
Its worth mentioning I do understand what double free is, being a c++ for when there is an attempt to release memory twice, but being Java, there is no control on that.
I have the following method:
private static Mat imageToMat(BufferedImage sourceImg) throws IOException {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            ImageIO.write(sourceImg, "jpg", byteArrayOutputStream);
            return Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()), Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }

The issue I have is that the second line of this method (ImageIO.write) throws the following error before my program crashes completely.
free(): double free detected in tcache2.
I have worked through it and I have identified it isnt an issue with ImageIO (I have removed that and done some basic manipulation to the bufferedimage and it throws the same message.
Some things worth mentioning about this environment.
This method works perfectly fine in a Windows 11/10/7 environment.
This occurs on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (on a VM box).
My first thought is that this is probably a issue with the openjdk version installed on the vm, so I attempted changing to OpenJDK from 19 to 23 (Note that on Windows it is openjdk 20, which runs fine).
Note that I dont have another available environment of Ubuntu outside of a VM (which im starting to suspect its to do with some graphics/accelleration issue, but I think I am clutching at straws at this point.
Has anyone seen anything similar to this when working with BufferedImages?

Can you [edit] the post with the stack trace from the generated error log file by java? typically a .log file in the working directory of the process. Also note that Errors like these might be caused by multple threads if you use plugins for ImageIO that store global data instead of thread local data for their state

Your application is probably using native libraries that can easily have a double free or some other typical memory usage of using C/C++ code. You haven't however provided enough information to help. Share the log details including the literal error/stack from the log. Just describing the errors is not helpful. Also share a [mre].

ImageIO's JPEG plugin uses native (bundled) libjpeg, but I've never seen this problem. Looks like you are also using OpenCV, which is another native library. I'd look into that.

Unfortunately there is no available stack trace. other than the double free being displayed.
Your right OpenCV is also part of this application. I have for the intent of isolating this issue disabled all processing of OpenCV and isolated it to this single method.
One thing that is worth mentioning is that this is a threaded application, which could speak to the native libraries being used by ImageIO. I didnt realise ImageIO was native, so will focus investigation on that, but my understanding is that is thread safe. perhaps not. will look deeper.
